# Use dart:html library in AngularDart

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-html

I want to know how to use (if it's possible) dart:html in angulardart. I try it in default example on webstorm when create a angulardart project (The todo list).

I try insert some dart code, but it doesn't work. It work only if I insert it in the OnInit auto implemented ngOnInit. It's that the only way? Use dart to manage DOM in AngularDart it's a correct practice?
I need AngularDart for the full functionally route system

Answer (score 2):

You can get at underlying dart:html elements in AngularDart in a number of ways:

for instance:

```
<div #myEl></div>
{{foo(myEl)}}

import 'dart:html';
@Component(...)
class ... {
  foo(DivElement div) {
    ...
  }
}
```

You can also get that div view ViewChild:

```
...
  @ViewChild('myEl')
  DivElement div;
...
```

And you can ask for it in your component's constructor:

```
@Component(...)
class MyClass {
  DivElement div;
  MyClass(Element e) : div = e;
  ...
```

And you can implement "functional directives," which don't have a class at all, but rather just call dart:html APIs on the component when its created:

```
@Directive(...)
void myFunctionalDirective(Element e) {
  ...
}
```

Hopefully one or more of these use cases satisfies your needs.

Do remember that any time you use the dart:html library, you may do things that AngularDart can't track, and you may get confusing behavior. Its best to let angular do as much as it can for you as possible, and only use dart:html as sort of the "back end" of some small components and let angular wire them together. But that is a very large topic that could fill a small book :)

Comment: I'm new in Dart and Angulardart and I need for University. I don't understand how to use last @Directive: in that function Will be initialize variables of DOM? Could you kindly write me example for every way about input text and a button that in click print that input in a DOM text elementi? For example this is HTML <input id="test-input"/> <button id="test-input">Read input</button> <p id="read-text" />. Really thanks for your answer

Comment: This is not something you want to do in the native DOM API, almost certainly. For this, you want class MyComponent { String written; String shown; } with template <input [(ngModel)]="written" /><button (click)="shown = written">Read Input</button> <p>{{shown}}</p>......To risk giving you correct but harmful advice, the functional directive approach would be @Directive(selector: "test-input") void neverWriteThisCode(Element e) { e.onClick((_) { document.getElementById('read-text').content = document.getElementById('test-input').value; }); }. Which is awful, unless your case is very very special

Comment: Ok so this is not the best way... Or angulardart or dart-lang. I Need find a way to manage/create route in dart-lang, otherwise I Switch on angulardart. Thank you so much